# Android SAXParser parse local stored xml file

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, local-storage, sax

Im using `SAX` to `parse` a `XML File` stored online. And then populate a custom `GridView`
This is working fine.
Now i want to download the XML File at the Application Start to the `local storage` and then parse it later.

**Parse:**

```
class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            gridView.setAdapter(new LkwAdapter(Lkw.this,itemList));
            showProgress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try{
                URL contURL = new URL(rUrl);
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                LkwParseHandler handler = new LkwParseHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(handler);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(contURL.openStream()));//THIS WORKS
                //xr.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("test.xml")));
                //THIS IS ONE OF MY MANY TRIES, what InputSource do i use?

                itemList = handler.getLkwItems();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

This works for an Online File!!
Then when i first Save the File and try to use that, the GridView stays empty!

**Save File:** (in a Thread on Splash Screen)

```
InputStream input = null;
FileOutputStream output = null;
try {
   URL url = new URL("http://test.com/test.xml");
   input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
   output = openFileOutput("test.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   int read;
   byte[] data = new byte[1024];
   while ((read = input.read(data)) != -1)
       output.write(data, 0, read);

   output.close();
   input.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
   }

   startActivity(i);
   finish();
}
```

Am I saving correct in the first place? what am i missing?

In this Question, you can see what I'm trying to do [Android Data handling and XML version control concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039269/android-data-handling-and-xml-version-control-concept)
In the end i want to either pass a `URL` or a `FilePath` to the `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody even looked at the question (Whats the deal here??) I got it working after hours using:

```
...
FileInputStream fis =  openFileInput("test.xml");
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);

xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
...
```